# NDepend Query to show const, enum, struct dependencies

Tags: ndepend

I wrote the following query in order to determine the dependencies between my solution and other assemblies.  We have a large library of Internal Nuget shared libraries which is used extensively, and I want to ensure these are included - hence I'm using 't' below to eliminate certain 3rd party assemblies but including our internal libraries.

This query works great, but I have realised that it only shows us dependencies where the dependency is a method call.  It doesn't include Constants, enums and structs.

How can I enhance the query below to show us  the detail of these and any other dependencies?

```
let t = Assemblies.WithNameWildcardMatchIn("xunit","RestSharp","NSubstitute","O2S*","EntityFramework","AxInterop*","AutoMapper","Autofac*","ADODB","mscorlib","System*", "Microsoft*","Infra*","Interop*").ToDictionary<IAssembly,String>(c=>c.Name)
from a in Application.Assemblies
from m in a.ChildMethods
from b in m.MethodsCalled
let isThirdParty = t.ContainsKey(b.ParentAssembly.Name)

select new { a,isThirdParty,m.ParentNamespace, m.ParentType,m.Name,DependsOnAssembly=b.ParentAssembly.Name, DependsOnNamespace=b.ParentNamespace,DependsOnParentType=b.ParentType,DependsOnMethod=b.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this refactored version of your query:

```
from a in Application.Assemblies
from m in a.ChildMethods
from b in m.MethodsCalled.Cast<IMember>().Union(m.FieldsUsed.Cast<IMember>())
let isThirdParty = b.IsThirdParty

select new { 
   a,
   isThirdParty,
   m.ParentNamespace, 
   m.ParentType,
   m.Name,

   DependsOnAssembly=b.ParentAssembly.Name, 
   DependsOnNamespace=b.ParentNamespace,
   DependsOnParentType=b.ParentType,
   DependsOnMember=b.Name
}
```

First we simplified it greatly by using `b.IsThirdParty` :)

Second we do a `Union<IMember>()` between `MethodsCalled` and `FieldsUsed`. So you get also all fields read and/or assigned in addition to methods called.

Concerning structure usage, as long as you use a member of the structure (constructor, property, field...) the dependency will be listed.

Concerning enum, if a method uses an enumeration, you'll see a dependency toward the instance field `EnumName.value__`.

However you won't see usage of constant nor enumeration values. The reason is that this information get lost in the IL code that NDepend analyze. Constant (and enumeration values are also constants) are replaced with their values within the IL code.

Hope this help !

---

As a side note, isn't the query result more readable from within the NDepend UI if you write instead:

```
from m in Application.Methods
select new { 
   m,
   thirdPartyMethodsCalled = m.MethodsCalled.Where(m1 => m1.IsThirdParty),
   applicationMethodsCalled = m.MethodsCalled.Where(m1 => !m1.IsThirdParty),
   thirdPartyFieldsUsed = m.FieldsUsed.Where(m1 => m1.IsThirdParty),
   applicationFieldsUsed = m.FieldsUsed.Where(m1 => m1.IsThirdParty)
}
```

[image: NDepend dependencies code query method field usage]